# The git source is not yet checked out when running Docker

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, bundler

I'm currently facing an error when trying to use a gem from GitHub.  I have the following in my Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'rack'
gem 'puma'

group :development do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'rerun', github: 'alexch/rerun', branch: 'master'
end
```

When I run `bundle install` from `Dockerfile` it works with a message like:

```
...
Installing sinatra 1.4.6
Installing listen 3.1.5 (was 3.0.6)
Using rerun 0.11.0 from git://github.com/alexch/rerun.git (at master@3e4c486)
Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 14 gems now installed.
...
```

However, when I go to start the container I get:

```
The git source git://github.com/alexch/rerun.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
```

I've seen similar issues but not related to Docker.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Turns out I was able to find the issue.  The problem was related to my Gemfile being used to build the Docker image.

I had not locally run a `bundle install` command which led to the `Gemfile.lock` not being updated.  Once I ran the command the following was added to my `Gemfile.lock`:

```
@@ -1,14 +1,20 @@
+GIT
+  remote: git://github.com/alexch/rerun.git
+  revision: 3e4c486304be406cb86180ef70ec24e9ae055ce4
+  branch: master
+  specs:
+    rerun (0.11.0)
+      listen (~> 3.0)
```

Turns out that was all I needed.  Once I had the updated file, rebuilt the image and ran the container everything worked as expected with `bundle exec rerun`.  So the catch was that I was using the `Gemfile.lock` to help with caching / version locking but failed to keep it updated with my `Gemfile`.

Comment: Waiting as fast as I can ... 2 days and I'll accept :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested there's an alternative.

During image creation, if your dockerfile runs `bundle install` it will generate a Gemfile.lock in the container. You can use docker run to get the contents, e.g.

`docker run web cat Gemfile.lock`

You can copy the contents and save a Gemfile.lock to your project directory.

Answer (score -1):

Worked to me:

`docker-compose run web bundle install`